# Spring boot microservices exception behaviour with @ControllerAdvice & @CircuitBreaker

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices

My question is related to exception behaviour in microservices.
Suppose we have a microservice(Let's say microservice-A) having a controller advice annotated class to handle all exceptions.

Also my microservice-A is calling one another microservice(let's say microservice-B). Assuming this call is happening from a service layer method annotated with `@CircuitBreaker(name="myService", fallback="myFallbackMethod")`

So if I introduce any runtime exception after the successful call to the microservice-B, will the fallback method execute, or will the `@ExceptionHandler` annotated method present in the `@ControllerAdvice` annotated class execute?

Attaching the piece of poc

```java
    //Microservice-A
    package com.example.iplservice.controller;
    
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    import com.example.iplservice.feign.MyFeignClient;
    import io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.annotation.CircuitBreaker;
    
    @RestController
    
    @RequestMapping("ipl")
    
    public class IplController {
    
        @Value("${ipl.team}")
        private String iplTeam;
    
        @Autowired
        private Environment env;
    
        @Autowired
        private MyFeignClient myFeignClient;
    
        @GetMapping("/team/hello")
        @CircuitBreaker(name = "cricketService", fallbackMethod = "getHelloFallBack")
        public ResponseEntity < String > getHello() {
            String body = myFeignClient.getHello().getBody();
            //introducing an error here!!
            int a = 2 / 0;
            System.out.println("-----------------" + a);
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello " + iplTeam + " : " + env.getProperty("local.server.port") + " : Called : " + body);
        }
    }
    //Microservice-A ends
```

```java
    //Microservice-A Controller Advice
    package com.example.iplservice.excetion;
    
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;
    
    @ControllerAdvice
    public class CricketExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    
        @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
        public ResponseEntity < String > handleGenericException(Exception ex) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Error From Controller Advice : " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    //Microservice-A Controller Advice ends
```

```java
    //Microservice-B
    package com.example.cricketersdetailservice.controller;
    
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
    import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    
    @RestController
    @RefreshScope
    @RequestMapping("/cricket")
    public class CricketController {
    
        @Value("${cricketer.team}")
        private String teamName;
    
        @Autowired
        private Environment env;
    
        @GetMapping("/team/hello")
        public ResponseEntity < String > getHello() {
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello " + teamName + " : " + env.getProperty("local.server.port"));
        }
    }
    //Microservice-B ends
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Can you add some example code?

Comment: I have attached the sample code, the behavior I am getting is that the circuit breaker fallback method is getting called irrespective of the controller advice, is this the normal flow?

Comment: Yes, definitively this is the expected behavior, because the Circuit Breaker will trigger for every exception by default (at least for resilience4j).

Comment: Thanks for the information..God bless 

Answer (score 0):

As I can see on the code, the fallback method will be triggered. Even tough the call to micro-service B was successful, the Circuit Breaker will watch every exception that occurs on the method `getHello`.

If you want to change this behavior, there are some alternatives:

- Decorate only the feign client method call with the circuit-breaker
- Separate the feign client call on a new method and annotate that method with `@CircuitBreaker`
- Configure the circuit-breaker to watch only some specific exceptions thrown by feign client

Check resilience4j docs [here](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/circuitbreaker#create-and-configure-a-circuitbreaker) and [here](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/circuitbreaker#decorate-and-execute-a-functional-interface)